# Stop Boinc from auto-start on system boot

Tags: 11.10, startup, boinc

I have installed Boinc and subscribed to the projects I used to have on my old Windows machine. Everything works fine with one exception. I did not see any option in Boinc Manager to specify if I want my job to start on system boot or not.

After a reboot I can clearly see in the processes that boinc is doing it's calculations even though the manager is not running. So, is there a way to stop this process to autostart? Should I create a startup script which starts 30-40 seconds after login and kills all boinc processes? This seems kind of drastic I think :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem. It's like that old saying: "If you want something done, do it yourself"

```
sudo update-rc.d -f /etc/init.d/boinc-client remove
```

This tells the system not to start the BOINC client at boot time.

In short, this is the init script for BOINC:

```
/etc/init.d/boinc-client
```

The solution wasn't hard to find, it's actually on their wiki page: [Stop_or_start_BOINC_daemon_after_boot](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/wiki/Stop_or_start_BOINC_daemon_after_boot)

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 15.10, using the `update-rc.d boinc-client remove` command, [as suggested in the official Boinc wiki](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/wiki/Stop_or_start_BOINC_daemon_after_boot), didn't work for me. 
Boinc continued to automatically launch at startup.

However this worked : `sudo systemctl disable boinc-client`